# Loop through and create array of objects

Tags: python, oop, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a list of objects in Python. The below code should (hopefully) explain what I'm doing:

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def CallMe(self):
        out = []
        #another (models) object is initialised here which is iterable
        for model in models:
            #create new instance of the called class and fill class property
            newobj = self.__class__()
            newobj.model = model
            out.append(newobj)
        return out


class Derived(Base):
    pass
```

I'm trying to initialise the class as follows:

```
objs = Derived.CallMe()
```

I want 'objs' to contain a list of objects which I can iterate through.

I get the following error in the stacktrace: `TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments` on the line that contains `newobj = self.__class__()`

Is there some way to do this or am I looking at the problem the wrong way?

Comment: Your question and the example do not show a need to use a class & classmethod. Is there one or could you just use a function as a factory to construct your list of objects? Simpler is usually better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that a `classmethod` doesn't receive an instance (`self`) as an argument. Instead, it receives a reference to the class object it was called on. Often this argument is named `cls` though this convention is somewhat less strong than the one for `self` (and you'll occasionally see code with names, like `klass`).

So rather than calling `self.__class__()` to create your instances, just call `cls()`. You'll get `Derived` instances if the function was called as `Derived.CallMe()`, or `Base` instances if called as `Base.CallMe()`.

```
@classmethod
def CallMe(cls):     # signature changed
    out = []
    models = something()
    for model in models:
        newobj = cls()    # create instances of cls
        newobj.model = model
        out.append(newobj)
    return out
```

Comment: So simple, yet just about the only thing I didn't try! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you made it a classmethod, its `self` argument is not an instance but the class itself.  So you want to do `self()`.  For this reason, it's customary to name that first argument of a classmethod not `self` but `cls`.